# TFS 2010 proxy is missing from install options on 64-bit server

Tags: tfs

When we install on a 32-bit server, we get the option to install the proxy server, but installing on an x64 only gives us the option to install the build service. Does TFS 2010 Server Proxy support Windows 2003 64-bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer:

2.1.3 64-Bit Windows Server 2003 Not Supported

No 64-Bit edition of Windows Server 2003 is supported.

To resolve this issue:

You must use a supported operating system.